# Is using an Azure VNet-to-VNet a feasible way to create a DMZ?

Tags: azure

**EDIT:** This question was originally asked during the legacy ASM days. Things are significantly different and the introduction of Network Security Groups makes this trivial to implement in a modern Azure environment.

---

I have a three-tier application running in Azure VMs.

This application has two back-end tiers and a web tier. This is split up into three cloud services - one for each tier.

The two back-end tiers use Azure Internal Load Balancing.

The web-tier only needs to communicate to the back-end on port 443.

Is it feasible to create a second VNet and use VNet-to-VNet connectivity for the front-end servers and put an ACL on it, so that it can only communicate with the back-end servers over 443? If so, where do I configure this ACL? Under no circumstances should the back-end servers be exposed to the Internet directly.

Comment: This can now be done with Network Security Groups.
http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/11/04/network-security-groups/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

This is not possible. See [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-acl/): Currently, you can specify network ACLs for endpoints only. You can’t specify an ACL for a virtual network or a specific subnet contained in a virtual network. Also, the [Virtual Network Security Whitepaper](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386611) might be useful.

---

Have a look [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/03/28/network-isolation-options-for-machines-in-windows-azure-virtual-networks/)

Basically, yes, you can have your front-end-server in one vnet, and your back-end server in another, and then restrict the access to the back-end using ACL's.

What you cannot do is restrict communication between the back-end servers using ACL's if they are in the same VNet. You need Windows Firewall or other measures for that.

To configure this, once you have your back-end servers in a VNet, use the "Endpoints" configuration of the back-end servers and add your `HTTPS/443` endpoint. Then, still on this endpoint, click "`MANAGE ACL`" on the bottom. Now, PERMIT your front-end network or just the `/32` IP Address(es), and `DENY` everything else (`0.0.0.0/0`)

See [the guide](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/03/28/network-isolation-options-for-machines-in-windows-azure-virtual-networks/) for more details

Comment: But I don't want to use public endpoints, as I'm using ILB.

Comment: According to [this](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/05/20/internal-load-balancing/), you can add ACLs to an ILB endpoint. That said, I haven't worked with ILB yet, so I can't tell you how :)

Comment: You can but I want to ACL the entire tunnel between the internal VNet and the "DMZ" VNet. Forget ACLs on individual endpoints, as these will not be the *only* servers/applications in these VNets.

Answer (score 0):

yes, check this out :

[image]

This is a DMZ using the HUB and spoke approach.

https://mouradcloud.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/blog/blog/2018/07/19/build-azure-hub-and-spoke-using-pfsense-nva-udr-vnet-peering-and-vpn-on-local-router/

Now if you want a pure 3 tiers without DMZ, see there :

https://github.com/MourIdri/azureiaascodev1